Cors Issue at Angular and NodeJS Backend
I have Cors Issues at my NodeJS Typescript Backend and Angular App with Vercel.
I want to send data from my node JS Server to my Angular App and retreive it there.
I have saw there a simmilar issues, but they are often not anweared or I have tried and did not work.
I use the latest NodeJS and Angular Version.
My vercel.json looks like this:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],

  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My Node JS:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Route für GET-Anfragen an die Root-URL
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

const allowCors = fn => async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  // another common pattern
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
  )
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end()
    return
  }
  return await fn(req, res)
}

const handler = (req, res) => {
  const d = new Date()
  res.end(d.toString())
}

module.exports = allowCors(handler)

// Server auf Port 3000 starten
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

On my Angular App i have this:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss'],
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any[] = []; // Typisierung entsprechend den erwarteten Daten anpassen

  private apiUrl = 'https://chat-backend-seven-tau.vercel.app/'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Beispiel für einen GET-Request, um alle Chats abzurufen
  getChats(): Observable<any[]> {
    // Optional: Erstellen der HttpHeaders, wenn du spezielle Header benötigst
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // Weitere Header können hier hinzugefügt werden, falls nötig
    });

    // Anfrage mit Headern, falls benötigt
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.apiUrl}`, { headers });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getChats().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.data = response; // Daten in der Komponente speichern
        console.log('Chats:', this.data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Fehler beim Abrufen der Chats:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}

I also restarted the Angular App again and it did not work.
How can I solve the issue? Thanks for any comment.

cors issue is from node side you have to allow cors policy to angular have got access to the url

ok and how should be the nodejs code look like? Because with  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') i thaugt it will work

no you have to allow the origin in the node js  header setting will not work

Need to do something like that
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});```


can you give me the whole nodejs code? Is the vercel.json then not needed?

  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "url",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE, POST, PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
      },
      "dest": "/index.ts"
    }
  ]
}


should i use this vercel.json?

yes but you have to mention the url * will not work

I got the same error again...backend: https://github.com/mark-baumann/chat-backend app: https://github.com/mark-baumann/chat-app

ok Baumann I've to look into the code I'll fix this issue and then back to you

thanks! It is really hard to find why the cors here have problems. I have the frontend on Vercel and Backend also on Vercel hosted
